# Button inner span not registering click

Tags: html, angularjs, event-handling

I have a simple button with a span inside it with some boostrap icon as its class. 
Nothing serious.

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.toggleMenuDropDown()" class="  cornerMenuButton menuButton">
                    <span class="fa fa-reorder"></span>
                    Menu
</button>
```

The problem is that the span part does not register the click. When I click on the rendered button where the icon is, the click is not registered. And I don't know why, or what might be causing that.

But when I add stop propagation to the button it all works fine. Like so:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.toggleMenuDropDown(); $event.stopPropagation()" class="  cornerMenuButton menuButton">
                    <span class="fa fa-reorder"></span>
                    Menu
</button>
```

It works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to know why you are using a span inside a button element but clarifying your question:

You need to add `ng-click` on the span element also. If you want only the span `ng-click` to work you need to add `event.stopPropagation()` to your `toggleMenuDropDown(event)` function passing event to this function.

The definition of `event.stopPropagation` is:

> The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to
> parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being
> executed. Tip: Use the event.isPropagationStopped() method to check
> whether this method was called for the event.

```js
$("#but").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
 });


$("#foo").click(function(){
 alert("parent click event fired !");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <button id="foo">button
<span id="but">

<span></button>
```

Comment: Maybe the span was not the best option, but I used just so I could have an element to add the icon CSS classes to inside the button. For style reasons and such. And if bubbling is happening, then I figured it should have worked by default. Why stopping the event at the button makes things right?

Comment: StopPropagation : In simple words stopPropagation stops event bubbling and event capturing. what is event bubbling, event bubbling  means if you have a number of elements enclosed one inside the other, then clicking on the innermost element starts a chain of event originating from innermost event towards outer i.e events gets propagated outwards,On the other hand, event capturing is just the opposite of event bubbling which means that event chain starts propagating from top most element to the innermost element.

Comment: hence to work ng-click in your span tag you need to stopPropogation on your button so that ng-click in your span will work!

Comment: I have added spinnet for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...Added z-index to my span and it worked out

```
.reorder{
  .fa {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats an interesting solution :D. But I'm curious as to why the span is not registering the click. Is event bubbling happening or event capturing? Why stopping the propagation on the button works out?

Comment: The icon and the span needed to have the position set for the z-index to have any effect.